# Print all variables in a class? - Python

Tags: python, class, shelve

I'm making a program that can access data stored inside a class. So for example I have this class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shelve

cur_dir = '.'

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, score, age=None, yrclass=10):
        self.name = name
        self.firstname = name.split()[0]
        try:
            self.lastname = name.split()[1]
        except:
            self.lastname = None

        self.score = score
        self.age = age
        self.yrclass = yrclass
    def yrup(self):
        self.age += 1
        self.yrclass += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = shelve.open('people.dat')
    db['han'] = Person('Han Solo', 100, 37)
    db['luke'] = Person('Luke Skywalker', 83, 26)
    db['chewbacca'] = Person('Chewbacca', 100, 90901)
```

So using this I can call out a single variable like:

```
print db['luke'].name
```

But if I wanted to print all variables, I'm a little lost.

If I run:

```
f = db['han']
dir(f)
```

I get:

```
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'age', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'name', 'score', 'yrclass', 'yrup']
```

But I want to be able to print the actual data of those.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
print db['han'].__dict__
```

Comment: Which is actually equal to `vars(db['han'])`, as it calls `__dict__`.

Answer (score 29):

> Rather than using [magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) , [Vars](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) could be more
>   preferable.

```
print(vars(db['han']))
```

Answer (score 15):

```
print(vars(objectName))

Output:
{'m_var1': 'val1', 'm_var2': 'val2'}
```

This will print all the class variables with values initialised.

Comment: Does it also print a list of all callable functions?

Answer (score 4):

Define [__str__](http://pyref.infogami.com/__str__) or [__repr__](http://pyref.infogami.com/__repr__) methods in your Person class and print the object.

Answer (score 2):

Just try [beeprint](https://github.com/panyanyany/beeprint)

after `pp(db['han'])`, it will print this:

```
instance(Person):
    age: 37
    firstname: 'Han',
    lastname: 'Solo',
    name: 'Han Solo',
    score: 100,
    yrclass: 10
```

no methods, no private properties.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a method to print all the attribute, you can use:

```
def get_attribute(self):
    """
    Prints all attribute of object
    """

    for i in (vars(self)):
        print("{0:10}: {1}".format(i, vars(self)[i]))
```

You then need to call the method:

```
db['luke'].get_attribute()
```

and it will print:

```
name      : Luke Skywalker 
firstname : Luke 
lastname  : Skywalker 
score     : 83 
age       : 26 
yrclass   : 10
```

Please note you can play around with the value {0:10} to change the spacing for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

`print(vars(self))`
or
`pprint(vars(self))`

and to access `self.variable` name

Eg.    `self._own_name`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the values of the variables you defined, you can do:

```
variables = [v for k, v in db['han'].__dict__.items() 
              
              # variable is not a python internal variable
              if not k.startswith("__") 
              and not k.endswith("__")
              
              # and is not a function
              and not "method" in str(v)
              and not "function" in str(v)]


print(variables) 
# ['Han Solo', 'Han', 'Solo', 100, 37, 10]
```

You will not print functions or  internal Python variables (start and end with `__`), called [dunders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65597366/1771155).