# How do I iterate over a list and print all attributes in a list

Tags: python, class, object

Ok so I have this code. I need to print attributes for each food in my list (created from a csv like this below

```
id,food,food_print,cal1,cal2,expi1999,expi2000,expi2001
1,bun,bun_bun,45.3434,199.32323,23.3333,45.4444,33.33333
2,burger,burger_bun,45.342343,200.34243,34.3333,0,9
3,pickle,pickle_seed,67.345454,34.3434,34,56,33
4,chicken,chicken_egg,44.34343,43.343343,43,434,34343
```

How do I print all values from  meals to include all rows?  Also when printing an object I get `__main__.City object at 0x0000023B6FD552E0>` How do I see what is in this? Inside the object?

```
import csv

class City(object):
    def __init__(self, food , foodprint, cal1, cal2, expi1999, expi2000, expi2001):
        self.food = food
        self.foodprint = foodprint
        self.cal1 = cal1
        self.cal2 = cal2
        self.expi1999 = expi1999
        self.expi2000 = expi2000
        self.expi2001 = expi2001

meals = []
with open('food.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    foodies = list(reader)
    del foodies[0]

    print(foodies)

for rows in foodies:
    meals.append(City(rows[3],rows[4],rows[1],rows[2],rows[5],rows[6],rows[7]))
```

Comment: Your last line does not make sense to me. Your CSV is in the same order as your parameters of the City Class, yet it looks like you are trying to re-order them into the wrong variables ??

Comment: get the value of an attribute `instance.attribute_name`

Comment: Also - this may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992803/print-all-variables-in-a-class-python